# Is Python UDF still inefficient in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm reading the Book: `Spark: "The Definitive Guide: Big Data Processing Made Simple"` which came out in 2018, and now is 2023, so the book mentioned that using UDFs written on Python aren't efficient, same with using Python code on RDD's, is still that true?

Comment: Not as efficient as what?  Python is a very convenient language, so you get stuff done more quickly.  Most Python `spark` code is just plumbing, doing I/O and passing things to spark methods, which run at full-speed.  In that case, the efficiency of the Python code is irrelevant.  For many projects, it simply doesn't matter.  FIRST make it work, THEN figure out if it is fast enough.

Comment: @TimRoberts OP refers to User Defined Functions. If written in Java, they can execute natively. If written in Python the nodes have to export the data to a python runtime, and load the results back in to Java (which the spark engine is written in). My advice, is to treat Spark like SQL, in that expecting it to execute functions written in Any other language will introduce a massive overhead.

Comment: UDFs still have issue with python, it's advised not to use them with python, compared for example with Scala where UDF are much faster, there are a lot of spark native functions that can be used instead of custom UDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old knowledge but still applicable as per below:

- UDF's are slower in general as Catalyst cannot optimize them - they are blackboxes.  See https://www.codemotion.com/magazine/ai-ml/big-data/light-up-the-spark-in-catalyst-by-avoiding-udf/
- For python vs. Scala UDF's, yes python is slower. Reading this https://medium.com/quantumblack/spark-udf-deep-insights-in-performance-f0a95a4d8c62 gives a good insight on things. I use Scala when I assist, so this is not my key area but, summarizing an excellent post:

  - Uses PySpark UDFs when the data volume is not big or need quick insights using simpler functions.
  - Build an internal library with re-usable Scala UDFs
  - Create Python wrappers to call Scala UDFs (interesting!)
- On RDDs, they cannot be optimized by Catalyst for pyspark or Scala. Should be using DataFrames, DataSets.